# I can‘t understand the better GaloisKey creating with Microsoft SEAL?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, key-generator, seal

This is the description of GaloisKey in seal / keygenerator.h from the Microsoft SEAL-3.4 library :

```
/**
    Generates and returns Galois keys. This function creates specific Galois
    keys that can be used to apply specific Galois automorphisms on encrypted
    data. The user needs to give as input a vector of Galois elements
    corresponding to the keys that are to be created.

    The Galois elements are odd integers in the interval [1, M-1], where
    M = 2*N, and N = poly_modulus_degree. Used with batching, a Galois element
    3^i % M corresponds to a cyclic row rotation i steps to the left, and
    a Galois element 3^(N/2-i) % M corresponds to a cyclic row rotation i
    steps to the right. The Galois element M-1 corresponds to a column rotation
    (row swap) in BFV, and complex conjugation in CKKS. In the polynomial view
    (not batching), a Galois automorphism by a Galois element p changes
    Enc(plain(x)) to Enc(plain(x^p)).

    @param[in] galois_elts The Galois elements for which to generate keys
    @throws std::logic_error if the encryption parameters do not support
    batching and scheme is scheme_type::BFV
    @throws std::logic_error if the encryption parameters do not support
    keyswitching
    @throws std::invalid_argument if the Galois elements are not valid
    */
    SEAL_NODISCARD inline GaloisKeys galois_keys(
        const std::vector<std::uint64_t> &galois_elts)
    {
        return galois_keys(galois_elts, false);
    }
```

How can I create a better Galois elements for the GaloisKey.

In a general way:

```
GaloisKey gal_keys = keygen.galois_keys();
```

But Ciphertext first rotation is right，second rotation is wrong.

The specific error is, for example, one of my ciphertexts is [0.0001,0.0001, ... 0.0001], after rotation, the decryption is [1.0000,1.2000,1.7000 ...]

Comment: You win the "most about crypto question of the month" award; I've pasted a link on our [chat @crypto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/the-side-channel). By the way, always include a language / runtime tag when posting, if just to gain enough attention (and have the code be highlighted correctly).

Comment: Oh, and when you're saying "is wrong" always indicate the exact error condition or how it is wrong.